# AngularJS and RequireJS dispose controller

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have been reading about **AngularJS** and **RequireJS** in order to load dynamically controllers on the fly.

This is the best tutorial I have found by **Dan Wahlin**:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx

My concern is how to dispose a controller when you don't need it. Because loading controllers on the fly at the end will come up with a lot of JavaScript loaded in the browser. **EXTJS** Loader I think has that functionality.

Appreciate any comment.

Thanks